# SharedPreference values not available between activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activities. One is the main activity. One is the Preference activity. I'm trying to change the background color of the activity based on the color selected in a RadioGroup in the Preference activity.

This is the class file for the main activity.

```
package com.example.mycsimodules;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ModList extends ActionBarActivity {
   SharedPreferences savedData;
   private String[] moduleArray = { "COMP 41600", "COMP 41620", "COMP 47330","COMP 30160", "COMP 30500", "COMP 40725", "COMP 41100", "COMP 41110" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mod_list);

    savedData=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",0);
    String colorMine=savedData.getString("color", "deflt");
    TextView head=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mymodlist);
    head.setText(colorMine);

    ArrayAdapter<String> moduleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     R.layout.activity_list_view, R.id.list1, moduleArray);
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mod_list);
    list.setAdapter(moduleAdapter);


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mod_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
        startActivity(i);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the class file for the Preference class.

```
package com.example.mycsimodules;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Preferences extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
   RadioGroup colorList;
   Button saveButton;
   SharedPreferences savedData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

    colorList=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.colorRadioGroup);
    saveButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.preferences, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==saveButton){
        RadioButton myColor=(RadioButton) findViewById(colorList.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String colorSelected=myColor.getText().toString();
        TextView label=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_color_is);
        label.setText(colorSelected);

        savedData=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=savedData.edit();
        editor.putString("color", colorSelected);
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();


    }

}
}
```

I haven't actually done the background color part. I'm just trying to display the value in a TextView currently. But it shows only the default value all the time. What I'm trying to do is.
Click on Settings. 
Click on RadioButton for color desired. 
Click on Save button. 
Click on back key to return to main activity.

I'm pretty new to this and might be doing something wrong. But I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
savedData=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",0);
```

it's diferent from

```
savedData=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

Use the same file when you open your `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. I can't believe I've been breaking my head over this all day. That was such a silly thing to do. You're a life saver.

Comment: No problem friend. :) It's a common mistake don't worry. If this solved your problem please mark it as solution. Have a great day.